# How to get BlueOcean Multibranch Pipeline to auto-kickoff a build when a change is pushed to GitLab?

Tags: git, jenkins, gitlab, jenkins-blueocean

How do you setup a BlueOcean Multibranch Pipeline to auto-kickoff a build when a change is pushed to a git/GitLab repository?

I have this working for a regular Maven Project (non multi-branch pipeline job).  In the normal Maven Project, there's a configuration section (Project -> Configure -> Build Triggers -> "Build when a change is pushed to GitLab").

I don't see that in the Multibranch Pipeline jobs.

How do you set Multibranch Pipeline jobs to automatically build when changes are pushed to git/GitLab?

Thanks

Comment: BlueOcean is only an interface. So search for triggering Jenkins builds from Gitlab.

Comment: clarifying the question to reflect the type of project - a multibranch pipeline using git/gitlab

Comment: what document do you follow? i want to do that but i stuck at it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not noted in the documentation.. Triggers are automatically accepted in a Multibranch Pipeline job.

You need to add the webhook to your Multibranch Project in GitLab though.

It can be added in this form: https://:/project/ to GitLab under Settings -> Web Hooks.